# Excel Return Whole row when it Matches Cell

Tags: vba, excel, vlookup

I have a workbook with two sheets.

Sheet 1 has all of the data.

Sheet 2 is currently blank and I am planning to use a VLOOKUP to return any row that matches the certain cell.

In sheet 1 in column E there are different values in each cell, I want to return any that say `tyre`

I want them to copy the whole row of data whenever column E contains the word tyre.
The word tyre is in Cell B1 in Sheet2

I have currently tried this code which is in sheet 2 but just getting a #VALUE! error.

```
 =VLOOKUP($B$1,'sheet1'!E:E,0,FALSE)
```

Comment: Why have you passed third parameter as 0, try 1 instead.

Comment: I don't think you will be able to return a whole row using just a single VLOOKUP ( technically you can but you will have to replace 3rd parameter for each VLOOKUP which will be very, I mean VERY inefficient). You have two options AFAIK, advanced filter or a VBA based solution.

Comment: Tried 1 instead of 0 but only returns one cell not the whole row. Will VBA be needed for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would rather use a VBA approach. Just run a macro which says:

```
Public Sub specialLookUp()
    Dim keyword As String: keyword = Sheets("sheet2").Range("B1").Value
    Dim countRows1 As Long, countRows2 As Long
    countRows1 = 2 'the first row of your dataset in sheet1
    endRows1 = 1000 'the last row of your dataset in sheet1
    countRows2 = 2 'the first row where you want to start writing the found rows
    For j = countRows1 To endRows1
        If Sheets("sheet1").Range("E" & j).Value = keyword Then
            Sheets("sheet2").Rows(countRows2).Value = Sheets("sheet1").Rows(j).Value
            countRows2 = countRows2 + 1
        End If
    Next j
End Sub
```

Please note that now you can hardcode the beginning and the end of your dataset in sheet1, since you've told me your data have not an ID or any kind of field which is mandatory.

Comment: It is empty sometimes, im assuming that is whyim getting the `subscript out of range` error?

Comment: Did you change the names of the sheets and the other variables according to your workbook? Plus, is there any column which is NEVER empty (I assume yes, if we're talking of a data sheet)? If that column, for example, is "B", then you should just replace "E" with "B" into the row of the `Do While` statement.

Comment: Note: `subscript out of range` comes if you're trying to access a collection of values but this collection does not have the element you look for. I imagine it's coming from the `Sheets(x)` access, proably because your sheet name is `Sheet1` rather than `sheet1` or because it's just another different name.

Comment: Ok no error now (missed a space out from a sheet name) but nothing actually happens when i run the macro

Comment: Try it now, I had made a mistake into the row transfer statement.

Comment: Still nothing when its ran

Comment: This is strange, I have tried this snippet into a sample set and it works. Can't you run it in debug and see what happens line by line? I fear you might have not changed `Do While Sheets("sheet1").Range("E" & countRows1).Value` not replacing the `E` with a column always filled.

Comment: The column E in sheet1 is'nt always filled, sometimes it has blank cells.

Comment: You don't have in your dataset a column which is always filled? I don't know, a date, or an ID? Usually there's always one at least, that's only to control the whole dataset. Try to replace this column and then run it in debug (if you don't know how, [here](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/DebuggingVBA.aspx) you go... but the code works on my sample data ;) )

Comment: There literally isn't any column that is filled top to bottom. Could an ignore nulls be added (not sure on excel/vba code)

Comment: If there's not any column that is filled top to bottom, then I think you should hardcode the end of your dataset. I've edited the code.