# Comparing and getting the corresponding row in excel

Tags: excel, compare, vlookup, conditional-formatting

I have 2 different excel data. 
Sheet 1

```
S2_Symbol  S3_SymbolInteraction
STE        AR1     Bind
PRI        HYQ     Bind
ILA        LOU     Bind
VIS        IJK     Bind
```

Sheet 2

```
Symbol  
STE       
PRI      
ILA        
VIS
LKY
UTY
SSG
```

I have to compare Symbol from 2nd sheet to S2_Symbol and S3_Symbol from sheet 1. If it matches any one of the columns in sheet 1, the corresponding entire row from sheet 1 should be my output.Can anyone help me with this? I've tried with VLOOKUP and Conditional formatting. I am trying with the following formula

```
=IF(OR(COUNTIF($A$3:$A$1003,I12)>0,COUNTIF($B$3:$B$994,I12)>0),**I12**,"not found")
```

Here i am getting only one value as output. How to get the entire column as output?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Excel Return Whole row when it Matches Cell](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26911168/excel-return-whole-row-when-it-matches-cell)

Comment: @Alexandru Cimpanu: This is no duplicate since it has *two* Lookup_values, whereas the other question has only one.

Comment: @ pnut I need the matching row to be separated either in separate sheet or in same sheet.

Comment: @ThomasLandauer, I flagged it as a possible duplicate because he might be able to extend that answer to solve hes problem. From my understanding in that answer he's just iterating through the data and searching for a match. I guess in this case he could still iterate but through 2 columns, one at a time. Or iterate once but in the search condition he could check 2 cells per row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all: You cannot have an entire row in just one cell. You need multiple cells (i.e. formulas) for that.

The two search criteria is what makes this a little complicated. I guess you need two separate `VLOOKUP()`'s for that. I assume you have your data starting at A1 and your "Sheet 2" in column E:

1. In F2: `=VLOOKUP($E2;A:$C;1;FALSE)`
2. Drag this to the right, into column G

Now, in columns F and G we have either your symbol or `N/A`. Now for the "Bind" column:

1. In H2: `=IF(ISNA(F2);VLOOKUP(G2;B:C;2;FALSE);VLOOKUP(F2;A:C;3;FALSE))` This gives you "Bind" in the relevant rows of H.

Remaining problem: The symbol is scattered over columns F and G. Do you care about that or is this good enough?

Comment: Thank you Thomas landauer. Ill try and get u back